# Want to add labels and textboxes on clicking a Href link

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC my code is as below,

```
    <div class="form-inline">
    <label class="control-label"><b>Length</b></label>

    <input type="text" name="Refinishing.Room.Length.Feet" id="Refinishing_Room_Length_Feet" style="width: 80px" class="floor-text" />Ft
    <input type="text" name="Refinishing.Room.Length.Inch" id="Refinishing_Room_Length_Inch" class="floor-text" />Inch

    <label><b>Width</b></label>

    <input type="text" name="Refinishing.Room.Width.Feet" id="Refinishing_Room_Width_Feet" class="floor-text" />Ft
    <input type="text" name="Refinishing.Room.Width.Inch" id="Refinishing_Room_Width_Inch" class="floor-text" />Inch<br />

    <a href="#">Add Room</a> / <a href="#">Remove Room</a>
</div>
```

and I want to add the contents of "<div>" on clicking the link "Add Room".
How can it be done?

Comment: smell of code request :)

Comment: Define "add" - you mean post to server or add somewhere else to the DOM or..?

Comment: I just want to add contents of Room. I am developing it in MVC. and the code is written in the view of MVC4.

Comment: [Everything you could ever need to know about jQuery is found in their api documentation. For instance, here's the .append() method](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: I just want to add content on clicking the href link "Add Room".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.clone()`  and `.append()`

```
 $('body').on('click','a.addroom', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var $cloned = $('.form-inline:eq(0)').clone();

     $('body').append($cloned);

 }); 


 $('body').on('click', 'a.removeroom' ,function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).closest('div').remove();
}); 
<a href="#" class="addroom">Add Room</a>
```

Here the contents of the div is cloned and appended to the body..

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/hFvvF/2/)

Comment: adding one more fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/KMtJa/1/, have a look might help

Comment: can this code meke a clone of my "<div class="form-inline">" which is with collection of labels & textboxes?

Comment: If I want to remove those then what sholud I have to do?

Comment: I have updated the code so that it works it add's a div and removes a div.. Check the post and the fiddle

Comment: But here it it adds "form-inline" double number of times than the previous one

Comment: and it doesn't removes the content which got added.

Comment: I have used .closest() in the code , which removes the div in which the button is present.. This logic does not remove the last added div.. I have fixed the code that adds the div multiple times.. Check fiddle again

Comment: It doeesn't removes the <div>.

Comment: I want to remove the <div class="form-inline">

Comment: its adding that but not removing that one

Comment: It removes all the Previous things inserted in the <div>